# is there any way to restrict acess to an attribute in servlet context

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I need to change the value of an object which is in Sevlet context at runtime.it is guaranteed by my application that only a single thread would reset the value of that attribute in Servletcontext at a time

**Issue** : my problem is while single thread is setting the value of the object many other thread's will be having read access to this object and they all could read  weird values as the object might be half set at the time of using it

is there any way by which i can restrict all threads the read access till the write thread is finished setting the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServletContext.setAttribute() always need Synchronization

put ServletContext.setAttribute() in Synchronization block.

so that only one thread will ad value at a time.

Comment: problem here is not that two thread might try to set the attribute. if its sure that only one thread will set this attribute.                but while 1 thread is setting this attribute several other threads might be having read access to this attribute.  i want to restrict these threads from reading till the writer thread is finished writing

Comment: when you put ServletContext.setAttribute() in Synchronization block all other threads are in wait state. till the writing is not completed, once writing is completed all other thread will get access to read

Answer (score 1):

Put a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) as servletcontext attribute and manage the desired object as map entry.